# Determining the extension of an e-mail attachment automatically (whether it's XLSX or CSV) and applying the right parsing technique

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have two Google Script codes that automate the process of importing email attachments from Gmail (it's automatically labeled) into Google Sheets. So far I managed to make it work for CSV and XLSX files separately. Please see both codes below. My question is: how do I combine those two codes into one, so that it could determine the file extension automatically and apply the right parsing technique when copying the contents of the files in the respective Google Sheet. Thank you!

**For XLSX files:**

```
function getXLSX() {

var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Invoicing").getThreads(0,1);

/* var message = thread[0].getMessages()[0]; // Get first message */
var messages = thread[0].getMessages();
var len = messages.length;
var message=messages[len-1] //get last message
var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message

var xlsxBlob = attachments[0]; // Is supposes that attachments[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.

//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet_new = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jRh8sj_jAaZKH4xbdpI9Q4to1tKuGWTTO2MzHlU").getSheetByName("Data drop");
/*for (var i = 0; i > sheet_new.length; i++) {
  var range = sheet_new[i].getRange("A:I");
     range.clearContents();
}*/
  sheet_new.clearContents();
 var range = sheet_new.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
range.setValues(data);

}
```

**For CSV files:**

```
function getCSV() {

var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Invoicing").getThreads(0,1);

/* var message = thread[0].getMessages()[0]; // Get first message */
var messages = thread[0].getMessages();
var len = messages.length;
var message=messages[len-1] //get last message
var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message

var csv =  attachments[0].getDataAsString();
var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);

var a = data.length ;
var b = data[0].length;

//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jRh8sj_jAaZKH4xbdpI9Q4to1tKuGWTTO2MzHlU").getSheetByName("Data drop");
sheet.getRange("A:J").clear();
 var range_final = sheet.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
range_final .setValues(data);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? In this modification, the mimeType is compared and each script is run. Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var thread = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Invoicing").getThreads(0,1);
  var messages = thread[0].getMessages();
  var len = messages.length;
  var message = messages[len-1]; //get last message
  var attachments = message.getAttachments(); // Get attachment of first message
  var blob = attachments[0]; // Is supposes that attachments[0] is the blob of xlsx file.
  blob.setContentTypeFromExtension();

  if (blob.getContentType() == MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL) {

    // Process for XLSX
    var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, blob).id;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0]; // There is the data in 1st tab.
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    Drive.Files.remove(convertedSpreadsheetId); // Remove the converted file.
    var sheet_new = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jRh8sj_jAaZKH4xbdpI9Q4to1tKuGWTTO2MzHlU").getSheetByName("Data drop");
    sheet_new.clearContents();
    var range = sheet_new.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
    range.setValues(data);

  } else if (blob.getContentType() == MimeType.CSV) {

    // Process for CSV
    var csv =  blob.getDataAsString();
    var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
    var a = data.length ;
    var b = data[0].length;
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1jRh8sj_jAaZKH4xbdpI9Q4to1tKuGWTTO2MzHlU").getSheetByName("Data drop");
    sheet.getRange("A:J").clear();
    var range_final = sheet.getRange(1,1, data.length,data[0].length);
    range_final.setValues(data);

  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes as follows.

  - The index of `0` of attachment files is the file you need.
  - The index of `0` of attachment files is XLSX file or CSV file.
  - Filenames of XLSX and CSV files have the extension of `.xlsx` and `.csv`, respectively.

#### Reference:

- [setContentTypeFromExtension()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setcontenttypefromextension)
  If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you so much for the help, it worked like a champ! I appreciate your responses a lot, they are always on point and really helpful! I'm sorry that I didn't let you know right away that your code works perfectly, I will respond to your solution in a timely manner in the future! Cheers

Comment: @Max Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.